# Rails 3 controller private methods as helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

is it necessary to mention the private methods in controller as `helper_methods` in controller? 
Like

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :check_something

  def new
    check_something
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

private

  def check_something
    redirect_to(root_path) and return if something
  end
end
```

Is the statement :  `helper_method :check_something` required ? if so why ?

And when i call a private method from a controllers action method is the `params` hash accessible in the private or the `helper` method ??

Comment: You can take out the helper method thing. And I'm pretty sure you have to pass it as a parameter to the `check_something` method. Additionally, this seems like it should be a `before_filter`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it is not necessary. You can always call `private` methods of your controller within your controller.

Also, `params` would be available automatically for the `private` methods within controller.

Answer (score 8):

I think you have misunderstood the 'helper_method' concept.

`helper_method` is used to make your controller method to act as a method as its in your helper modules

So inside your controller, you can always access your private method without the '`helper_method`' section

and if you add a controller method as a helper method, as you have already done, in your view you can simply call it

and for your second question, yes params hash is accessible via controllers private methods

HTH

Answer (score 3):

No need to mention a private method as helper method in your controller. You can directly call them from another methods from the same controller by passing parameters like params, or any thing.

```
class ContorllerName < ApplicationController
 def index
  private_method(params)
 end
 private
 def private_method(vals)
   vals
 end 
end
```